# GoLang: main not finding shared library used by module

Tags: linux, go

I'm building a module in go, it looks something like this:

```golang
package eos

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/vendor/MyLibrary/1.14.2/Bin/Linux -lMY_SDK-Linux-Shipping
#cgo CFLAGS: -I ${SRCDIR}/vendor/MyLibrary/1.14.2/Include
#include "my_sdk.h"*/
import "C"

func useMyCFunc() void {
    C.myCFunc()
}
```

Then I have `hello.go` which is my main:

```golang
package main

import (
    "helloworld/eos"
)

func main() {
    eos.useMyCFunc()
}
```

The directory structure is as follows:

```
-helloworld/
|
- hello/
    |
    - hello.go
|
-eos/
    |
    - eos.go
    |
    - vendor/
        |
        - (all the required lib files)
```

These are the commands I run to build the program:

```sh
cd eos
go mod init helloworld/eos
cd ../hello
go mod init helloworld/hello
go mod edit -replace helloworld/eos=../eos
go mod tidy
go build .
```

None of these return any kind of error.
However, when I run `go run .` from `/hello`, I get this error:

```
/tmp/go-build2142984290/b001/exe/hello: error while loading shared libraries: libMY_SDK-Linux-Shipping.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This file does exist, and is located at `helloworld/eos/vendor/MyLibrary/1.14.2/Bin/Linux/libMY_SDK-Linux-Shipping.so`, as specified in the LDFLAGS of `eos.go`.

Why can `hello.go` not find this file?

Comment: Don'i use `go run`. It's a convenience wrapper for some common `go build` and execute cases. Your use of cgo flags makes it a special case that `go run` is not designed to handle.

Comment: Oh, did not know that. How can I run my script then? go build . returns nothing (when there should be at the very least some print statements)

Comment: See [Go command: Compile packages and dependencies](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies). `go build` builds the executable from source. To build and run the executable on Linux from your `hello` directory. `go build . && ./hello`.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what @rocka2q mentioned about CGo, `useMyCFunc()` needs to be capitalized for it to be accessible to outside of the `eos` package.